# How do I create new spreads

Tags: adobe-indesign

when I add 6 pages in Indesign they create a multi-page spread, 8 pages in a row, instead of adding 3 new 2-page spreads. how do I create 2-page spreads?

Answer (score 3):

Simply drag pages next to each other in the **Pages** panel.

You may need to select the `Allow Document Pages to Shuffle` option in the Pages Panel menu.

If your master pages are set up as spreads (facing pages) simply clicking the `New Page` icon at the bottom of the **Pages Panel** will add pages in spread fashion rather than a single page fashion.